# Refreshing a layout requires a resize?

Tags: qt, layout, resize, refresh, qmainwindow

I'm trying to refresh a `QWidget` on a `QMainWindow`, actually I just change it's layout which is a `QVBoxLayout` filled with `QGroupBoxs`

So, when a certain signal is emited, the `QMainWindow` hide all the `QWidget`s present in it's layout (before deleting them), then make new ones and `show()` them. The thing is that, 90% of the time, the new list of `QWidget`s is larger. So when the refresh is done, the new `QWidget`s actually show but the `QMainWindow` is at the old size ! A simple resize (with mouse) makes the `QMainWindow` to be resized to the proper size.

Is there any function to apply on the `QWidget` ? on it's layout ? on the `QMainWindow` ?

I tried adjustSize() on each of them, but didn't work

Comment: Why do you expect the main window to resize when you show child widgets, have you told it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to naturally work, so you're doing something wrong. The default `sizeConstraint` of the layout on a widget is to only grow the widget if it's too small. You can change it to both grow and shrink the widget.

1. You must be adding the new widgets to the layout.
2. Your main window must not have a `minimumSize()`. If you derive from a widget that does return a nonzero `minimumSize()`, you must override it and return a zero size.
3. You don't have to hide the child widgets before `delete`ing them. It's pointless. Just delete them, Qt handles it properly.

See the complete example below. Tested on OS X and Windows XP + MSVC.

```
//main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

static int pick() { const int N = 10; return (qrand()/N) * N / (RAND_MAX/N); }

class Window : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QLayout * layout;
public:
    Window() {
        layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        QPushButton * button;
        button = new QPushButton("Randomize", this);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(randomize()));
        layout->addWidget(button);
        button = new QPushButton("Grow", this);
        button->setCheckable(true);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), SLOT(grow(bool)));
        layout->addWidget(button);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
private slots:
    void randomize() {
        // remove old labels
        foreach (QObject * o, findChildren<QLabel*>()) { delete o; }
        // add some new labels
        int N = pick();
        while (N--) {
            layout->addWidget(new QLabel(QString(pick(), 'a' + pick()), this));
        }
    }
    void grow(bool shrink)
    {
        QPushButton * button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
        if (shrink) {
            button->setText("Grow && Shrink");
            layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
        } else {
            button->setText("Grow");
            layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint);
        }
    }
};

int main(int c, char ** v)
{
    QApplication app(c,v);
    Window w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```